# Azure Function HttpTrigger with Cosmos DB input

Tags: c#, triggers, azure-functions, azure-triggers, cosmosdbtrigger

I am trying to create an Azure Function HttpTrigger with cosmos DB input binding.
But it is giving me a type error.

[image: Http trigger]

Here is what I am trying:

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(IReadOnlyList<Document> inputDocs, HttpRequest req, IAsyncCollector<Document> outputDocs, ILogger log)
{
}
```

And it is giving me the following error:

```
2019-06-03T06:48:35.646 [Error] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.HttpTrigger1'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Can't bind CosmosDB to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document]'.
Possible causes:
1) Tried binding to 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient, Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' but user type assembly was 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[[Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document, Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e.
2) Tried binding to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray, Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' but user type assembly was 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[[Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document, Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e.
3) Tried binding to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB.CosmosDBExtensionConfigProvider+DocumentOpenType, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' but user type assembly was 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[[Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document, Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e.
```

Can anyone help me with the type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here for an example which is pretty much what you are doing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/cosmos-db?tabs=csharp#retrieve-a-list-of-documents

```
[FunctionName("CosmosDBSample")]
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")] HttpRequestMessage req,
    [DocumentDB("test", "test", ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDB", sqlQuery = "SELECT top 2 * FROM c order by c._ts desc")] IEnumerable<object> documents)
{
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, documents);
}
```